# Getting pictures from TikZiT to LaTeX and seeing them in PDF format

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdftex, pdf

I'm using TikZiT[(see link)](http://tikzit.sourceforge.net/) to draw graphs with nods and edges. 
How to translate that picture to pdf version of my LaTeX document if possible.
There is a code below picture in TikZiT which I copy paste to LaTeX document but it doesn't show the picture in pdf format and I don't know what exactly I'm missing here.
I only have `\usepackage{tikz}` in preamble of LaTeX document.

example of TikZiT code that I copy paste to LaTeX:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
    \node [style=newstyle] (0) at (0, -0) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (1) at (0, 0.5) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (2) at (0.5, 0.5) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (3) at (1, 0.5) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (4) at (0.5, -0) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (5) at (1, -0) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (6) at (1, 0.5) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (7) at (1, -0) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (8) at (1, 0.5) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
    \draw [style=simple] (3) to (5);
    \draw [style=simple] (5) to (1);
    \draw [style=simple] (3) to (0);
    \draw [style=simple] (2) to (4);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
/* picture in TikZiT represents six nodes and few lines connecting them /*
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! It would be appreciated if you would complete your code to form a complete, small document people can compile to play with. How exactly are you adding this to you document? (What environment are you putting it in?) And what error messages/warnings do you get? Normally, those kinds of commands would be in a `tikzpicture` environment, and you would have definitions somewhere of the styles you are using (`simple`, `newstyle`). Also, I suspect you're missing definitions of layers and the relevant libraries. If this is what TiKZiT gives you, I think you'd be better to learn TiKZ.

Comment: You probably need parts of the preamble in your document. Details of how to find this are at http://tikzit.sourceforge.net/manual.html.

Comment: After playing with the tool for a little bit, it's a good tool—but it does not define the styles for you.  You must do this yourself (but it really isn't difficult).

Answer (score 6):

OK. I compiled and installed TiKZit in order to retrieve the rest of the default preamble. The only thing I don't know is what the definition of `newstyle` should be. I guess this is your own. Here, I've just made it the same as `simple` but in green rather than black.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{edgelayer,nodelayer,main}

\tikzstyle{none}=[inner sep=0pt]

\tikzstyle{rn}=[circle,fill=Red,draw=Black,line width=0.8 pt]
\tikzstyle{gn}=[circle,fill=Lime,draw=Black,line width=0.8 pt]
\tikzstyle{yn}=[circle,fill=Yellow,draw=Black,line width=0.8 pt]

\tikzstyle{simple}=[-,draw=Black,line width=2.000]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[-,draw=Black,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},line width=2.000]
\tikzstyle{tick}=[-,draw=Black,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\draw (0,-0.1) -- (0,0.1);}},line width=2.000]

% this are just for tikzit's display, I think
% \usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
% \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
% \newlength{\imagewidth}
% \newlength{\imagescale}

\tikzstyle{newstyle}=[% this is a custom style - you need to replace with whatever definition you are using
  -,draw=Green,line width=2.000]

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
      \node [style=newstyle] (0) at (0, -0) {};
      \node [style=newstyle] (1) at (0, 0.5) {};
      \node [style=newstyle] (2) at (0.5, 0.5) {};
      \node [style=newstyle] (3) at (1, 0.5) {};
      \node [style=newstyle] (4) at (0.5, -0) {};
      \node [style=newstyle] (5) at (1, -0) {};
      \node [style=newstyle] (6) at (1, 0.5) {};
      \node [style=newstyle] (7) at (1, -0) {};
      \node [style=newstyle] (8) at (1, 0.5) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
      \draw [style=simple] (3) to (5);
      \draw [style=simple] (5) to (1);
      \draw [style=simple] (3) to (0);
      \draw [style=simple] (2) to (4);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: 6 node graph]

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare the layers and the two missing styles. Not sure what the style defintions should be so I just set them to draw `thick` lines:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% -------------------------------------- Declare the layers
\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{edgelayer,nodelayer,main}

%% -------------------------------------- Declare the styles
\tikzset{newstyle/.style={thick}}
\tikzset{simple/.style={thick}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
    \node [style=newstyle] (0) at (0, -0) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (1) at (0, 0.5) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (2) at (0.5, 0.5) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (3) at (1, 0.5) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (4) at (0.5, -0) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (5) at (1, -0) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (6) at (1, 0.5) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (7) at (1, -0) {};
    \node [style=newstyle] (8) at (1, 0.5) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
    \draw [style=simple] (3) to (5);
    \draw [style=simple] (5) to (1);
    \draw [style=simple] (3) to (0);
    \draw [style=simple] (2) to (4);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP can figure out what they are by viewing the preamble (see http://tikzit.sourceforge.net/manual.html).

Comment: TikZiT is now being hosted at GitHub. See https://tikzit.github.io/ for how to use and to download